# w3schools multiple slideshow tutorial - additional slideshows

Tags: javascript, slideshow

This is the JS for a page which has multiple elements. Each triggers it's own modal slideshow. Works for two but when I attempt to add a third, it fails. 
Logical first step is to: var slideID = ["mySlides1", "mySlides2", "mySlides3]. And likewise add the .mySlides3 in the CSS. 
But there must be more to it. 
Maybe if I had an explanation for what these lines were doing: 
showSlides(1, 0);
showSlides(1, 1);

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow_multiple

Original Code which works with two slideshows (w3Schools.com)

```
var slideIndex = [1,1];
/* Class the members of each slideshow group with different CSS classes */
var slideId = ["mySlides1", "mySlides2"] 
showSlides(1, 0);
showSlides(1, 1);

function plusSlides(n, no) {
  showSlides(slideIndex[no] += n, no);
}

function showSlides(n, no) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName(slideId[no]);
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex[no] = 1} 
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex[no] = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none"; 
  }
  x[slideIndex[no]-1].style.display = "block"; 
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to explain what is happening in practice - it will be hard to debug this while all we know is 'it's not working'. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks MandyShaw, I edited for clarity.

Comment: At first glance, it looks like `slideIndex` needs an additional value for the third slideshow, and you may need to call `showSlides(1, 2);` to display the first image for it as well.

Comment: By the way, I would not suggest this code to someone just learning how to code. That code is pretty awful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your slideIndex and slideId to include members for the third slideshow. Then call showSlides for the third group.

```
var slideIndex = [1,1,1];
var slideId = ["mySlides1", "mySlides2", "mySlides3"]
showSlides(1, 0);
showSlides(1, 1);
showSlides(1, 2);
```

Of course this assumes you have duplicated one of the slideshows HTML and changed the IDs accordingly.

Also, don''t forget to add the .mySlides3 class to the CSS at the top of the page.

```
.mySlides1, .mySlides2, .mySlides3 {display: none}
```

Comment: That works. I will apply myself to learning what's happening with the slideIndex and showSlides (1 , x); Really appreciate your help.